# I was embarrassed by you

Tags: passive-voice

When you say "I was embarrassed by you", is it ever possible for you to mean that "you embarrassed me"? In other words, is it possible to convey the passive voice by "I was embarrassed by you"?

Comment: your language is a bit perplexing but if I understood your question I say it looks correct. 
"I was embarrassed by you" will do the job in passive usage.

Comment: [Couldn't resist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mBAvTtzWQ4). Yeah, it's usage is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and using it in passive voice is not so uncommon: "I was embarrassed by how you acted tonight" or "I was embarrassed by what you said yesterday".

Comment: Are you suggesting that the only salient interpretation of your examples are respectively "How you acted tonight embarrassed me" and "What you said yesterday embarrassed me"? If so, I wonder why they cannot be interpreted as, respectively, "I felt embarrassed by how you acted tonight" or "I felt embarrassed by what you said yesterday".

Comment: I'm not suggesting interpretations, but rather showing common usage of passive voice.  P.S. Considering that the feeling of embarrassment is a personal and subjective experience, is **being** embarrassed (by someone) really different than **feeling** embarrassed by them? What is the difference in meanings of "I was embarrassed by how you acted tonight" and "I felt embarrassed by how you acted tonight"?

Comment: Do you think that 'I felt embarrassed by how you acted tonight' means the same thing as does 'How you acted tonight embarrassed me'???

Comment: Yes, I do think that, and I gave you my reasons for it. Care to explain the difference in meaning (not syntax or semantics) between those two?

Comment: Well, I don't know, they may mean the same thing, but I think that technically they're not the same syntactically or semantically. "I felt embarrassed..." focuses on my feeling, which is a state of my mind, whereas "Your action embarrassed me" focuses on an event of it embarrassing me, rather than on a state of my mind.

Comment: Me and you can go out with the same friend, and I can be embarrassed by what he does/says, while you may not. I understand your point about feelings vs reality, but embarrassment is a social construct rooted in culture, customs, and relationships between people; it's so very subjective that IMHO there's no universal sense of "embarrassment" that can be detached from perception.